# Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a diferentiable function such $f'(x) = [f(x)]^2 $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function and $f(0) = 0$.
If $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ we have  $f'(x) = [f(x)]^2 $ then $f(x) = 0$,  $\forall x \in \mathbb R$

My attempt
$f$ is continuons then $f^2$ so $f'$ is continuons too.. By FTC we have $f(b) - f(a)= \int_a^b f'(t)dt$
 so choosing $[0,x]$ implies $f(x) = \int_0^x [f(t)]^2dt$
and i dont know how to finish this.

Comment: Divide by $1/f^2(x)$ and then integrate the equation: $\frac{f'}{f^2} = 1 \implies \int_{f(a)}^{f(x)} \frac{dy}{y^2} = \int_a^x 1\cdot dx$ where $a$ is a constant.

Comment: @Winther How can you do $1/f(x)^2$?

Comment: @egreg i think .. if $f(x)^2 = 0$ then $f'(x) = 0$ and so f is constant.. by $f(0) = 0$ gives the result..

Comment: @egreg The simplest approach is to assume the existence of an $a$ s.t. $f(a) \not = 0$. Then we can divide by $f^2(x)$ for all $x$ in a small interval around $a$ to deduce that the solution is $f(x) = \frac{f(a)}{1-(x-a)f(a)}$ then proceed to derive a contradiction.

Comment: @Winther thank you very much .. so $f(0) \neq 0$ and then we have your contradiction ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f'(x)=(f(x))^2$, the function $f$ is non decreasing; since $f(0)=0$, we have $f(x)\ge0$ for $x>0$. If $I=\{x>0:f(x)>0\}$ is not empty, then it is an open interval of the form $(a,\infty)$. (Note that $f(a)=0$, otherwise $a\ne\inf I$, but this is not relevant.)

Now, in the interval $I$, the function $f$ satisfies
$$
1-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}=0
$$
and so, since this is the derivative of $x\mapsto x+\frac{1}{f(x)}$,
$$
x+\frac{1}{f(x)}
$$
is constant on $I$, say $x+1/f(x)=k$. This can be written
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{k-x}
$$
This is absurd, because $f(x)<0$ for $x>k$, contradicting the fact that $I=(a,\infty)$ and $f(x)>0$ for $x>a$.

Similarly we can exclude that $J=\{x<0:f(x)<0\}$ is non empty.

It has been observed in the comments that other contradictions can be used; for instance, the constant $k$ can be computed by taking any point $x_0>a$, so
$$
k=x_0+\frac{1}{f(x_0)}\ge x_0
$$
which means the function $f$ is not defined at $k\in(a,\infty)$: contradiction.

Comment: Since there is a pole at $k=x_0+\frac1{f(x_0)}$, the sign change itself is not so much a contradiction. However, the existence of the pole itself tells us that the function is not defined or not differentiable at $x=k$, contradicting some basic assumptions.

Comment: @LutzL We know that $k<0$, or the function wouldn't be differentiable for $x>0$ (which is the domain we're working in). But then $f$ would be negative.

Comment: No, per assumption, the domain is all of $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is differentiable there. And even if the discussion is restricted to $[x_0,\infty)$, the value of $k$ as above follows from evaluation at $x_0$ and thus $k>x_0$, so the pole occurs in the considered domain.

Comment: @LutzL Is it really relevant? The fact that $f(x)<0$ for $x>k$ *is* a contradiction. Just pick up the contradiction you like the most.

Comment: Yes it is. Because your contradiction is to monotonicity. But the monotonicity follows from the mean value theorem which is not applicable if there is a singularity inside the interval. (Correction to the mixup above: $x_0$ is the first point $x$ mentioned above with $f(x_0)>0$, so that $a<x_0$ in $I=(a,\infty)$.)

Comment: @LutzL I'm assuming the function is monotonic, so I can apply the mean value theorem. Then I find a contradiction; more than one, actually. Why can't I choose the one I prefer? However, I added your point of view.

Comment: You are right, this is a question of taste or fundamentalism. Assumptions + $f'\ge 0$ implies monotonicity, a contradiction against monotonicity is thus a contradiction against the assumptions. Still, I think a pole is a more blatant contradiction than a sign change.

Answer (score 3):

$$F(x,y)=y^2$$ is continuously differentiable, so by a theorem of Cauchy $-$ extending Picard-Lindelöf $-$ local existence and uniqueness of solutions of the differential equation $$y'=F(x,y)$$ follows. Which means, among other things, that every solution is unique where it is defined. Since $$y(x)\equiv0$$ is a solution that is defined everywhere, it is the unique solution with initial condition $$y(0)=0.$$

Comment: It might be nice to sketch the proof of the extension of Picard-Lindelof. That is, we recursively apply Picard-Lindelof to a sequence of IVPs whose initial conditions are taken from the endpoints in the previous solution. Then we need some estimate that ensures that we only need finitely many intervals to get to any given point in the domain of the solution. I say this because the fact that the maximal domain doesn't depend on the Lipschitz constant(s) is fairly subtle, since Picard-Lindelof gives a domain in terms of the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: @Ian: That would be the discussion of maximal solutions, which is not necessary here. Cauchy only needs to regard that on any bounded region the maximum of the norm of the $y$-derivative is a Lipschitz constant.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to go as far as the maximal domain, but still, the recursive technique of the proof is good to know, and isn't taught very often.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a very similar one yesterday. We argue as follows. Since $f'(x) = f(x)^2$, $f(x)$ is increasing. Suppose $f(x)$ is not identically zero; we will get a contradiction. Replacing $f(x)$ by $-f(-x)$ if necessary, we can assume there is some $x_0 > 0$ for which $f(x_0) > 0$. Then since $f(x)$ is increasing, $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \geq x_0$. The condition $f'(x) = f(x)^2$ translates into
$${\partial \over \partial x}\bigg({1 \over f(x)}\bigg) = -1$$
This is equivalent to 
$${\partial \over \partial x}\bigg({1 \over f(x)} + x \bigg)= 0$$
This holds for all $x \geq x_0$. Hence for some constant $C$, for all $x \geq x_0$ one has
$${1 \over f(x)} + x = C$$
This is the same as
$$f(x) = {1 \over C - x}$$
However , for large enough $x$,  ${1 \over C - x}$ is negative, not positive as it should be since $x \geq x_0$. Thus we get a contradiction.

Comment: Isn't this the same as my solution?

Comment: I didn't see your solution, sorry about that. Do you want me to delete it?

Comment: Oh, no, the comments will explain. I'm just surprised that yours received a vote and mine didn't.

Comment: Ok, I've upvoted you :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there exist $a\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(a)\not= 0$. Now since $f$ is continuous there exist an interval $I$ around $a$ where $f(x)\not = 0$ for all $x\in I$. On this interval we can safely divide the ODE by $f^2$ and integrate the equation to obtain

$$\frac{f'}{f^2} = 1\implies \int_{f(a)}^{f(x)}\frac{dy}{y^2} = \int_a^x dx \implies f(x) = \frac{f(a)}{1-(x-a)f(a)}$$

This solution shows that $f(x) \not =0$ for all $x$ and is therefore also valid for all $x$. However this contradicts $f(0) = 0$ so $f(x) \equiv 0$ is the only solution.

${\bf Edit}$: The argument above breaks down if $1-(x-a)f(a) = 0$ for $x\in(0,a)$ as we cannot integrate the ODE back to $x=0$ to give us the contradiction without integrating past a singularity. One can try to rule out this possibility, but then the other answers here give a much simpler way to arrive at the desired conclusion.

Comment: You prove that $f(x)\ne0$ where the solution is defined, but this set doesn't contain $0$ by assumption.

Comment: @egreg I disagree. I show that if $f(a) \not= 0$ for an arbitrary $a$ then $f(x) \not= 0$ for all $x$. The converse of this is that if $f(0)=0$ then there cannot be a $x$ s.t. $f(x) \not= 0$.

Comment: Sorry, but what you get is valid only in the domain where you consider the function, which doesn't contain $0$. The fact that the formula makes sense also for other values of $x$ means nothing. For instance, if you show that a function is increasing in a neighborhood of $a$, you can't say it's increasing everywhere, can you?

Comment: @egreg You are right that this does not work (but it is for the wrong reason). Lets forget about the condition $f(0)=0$ and lets just say that I have a solution to the ODE where all I know is that there is an $a$ s.t. $f(a)\not =0$. Why can’t I integrate the ODE backward from $x=a$ to $x=0$ to conclude that $f(0)\not = 0$? The ODE is well-behaved and the formula, as long as it is non-singular, is not meaningless - it is the true solution. The problem here as I see it is that we cannot guarantee that $1-(x-a)f(a) \not= 0$ for $x\in[0,a]$ so that we cannot integrate past a possible singularity.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea can work, even in a much more general setting. Since $f(0)=0$ we know that $|f(x)|\leq 1$ on some interval $[-a,a]$ where $a > 0$. Then on this interval $|f'(x)|=|f(x)|^2\leq|f(x)|$. This inequality alone is enough to ensure that on this interval $$|f(x)|\leq\frac{|x|^n}{n!}$$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Proceed by induction from the base case $n=0$: $$|f(x)|=|\int_0^xf'(t)dt|\leq\int_0^x|f'(t)|\,|dt| \leq \int_0^x|f(t)|\,|dt|\leq \int_0^{|x|}\frac{t^n}{n!}dt=\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

From this it follows that $f$ is indentically zero on $[-a, a]$.  This reasoning works around any zero of $f$. Therefore the set of zeroes has no supremum or infimum and so it must be the entire real line.