# $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) = (f(x))^2$ implies $f = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Problem: Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with
$f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) = [f(x)]^2$.Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My incomplete attempt: Consider an interval $[0, x]$ . Thus, by the mean value theorem, 
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = f'(c_x) = (f(c_x))^2
$$
thus, 
$$
f(x) = (f(c_x))^2 x . 
$$

So, if there is any $ x_0 $ such that $ f (x_0) \neq  0 $ can this argument be applied to arrive at a contradiction?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1144019/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3226453/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1132213/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3441509/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2533837/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2152147/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f%27(x)%20%3D%20%5Bf(x)%5D%5E2%24&p=1)

Comment: Try differentiating both sides of $f'=f^2$ to get a differential equation you can solve for $f'$. I guess that should do it.

Comment: @user108903 You obtain $f''=2f'f$, though.

Answer (score 0):

The function $F(y,t)=y^2$ is locally Lipschitz, therefore by Picard-Lindelof the Cauchy problem $$\begin{cases}f'(t)=(f(t))^2\\ f(0)=0\end{cases}$$

has exactly one maximal solution. The constant zero function is a solution, therefore $f=0$.